PrimeNG table row selection query
The table works: headers fill, rows fill with data, columns sort. Single row selection doesn't work.
p-table:
<p-table [value]="releases" [columns]="headers" responsiveLayout="scroll"
    [paginator]="true" [rows]="pageRows" dataKey="index" 
    (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)"  selectionMode="single"  
    [(selection)]="selectedRelease" [resizableColumns]="true" sortMode="multiple">

onRowSelect:
  // onRowSelect method
  onRowSelect(event: any) {
    this.messageService.add({ severity: 'info', summary: 'Release Selected', detail: event.data.name });
  }

The function is called, but when breaking at the message call the event.data and event.index are undefined. This worked before an Angular/PrimeNG upgrade. Angular 17.3, PrimeNG 17.16.1. Thanks for any comments

please share  a stackblitz with the issue replicated reference in this example the index in undefined and data has a value.

Thanks for your example, please see answer below.

I had omitted the iterator variable on the body template. I had
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-release>
  <tr [pSelectableRow]>

where I needed
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-release>
    <tr [pSelectableRow] = "release">

I should have put more of the p-table code on the question. This did work before the framework upgrade. I edited it for other reasons and introduced this. Thanks anyway
